# onDrag called for each RecyclerView.ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drag

My onDrag method seems to be called for each RecyclerView.ViewHolder that exists in RecyclerView. Does anyone know how to prevent this and make sure it is only called once?

**ViewHolder**

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnLongClickListener, OnDragListener {
    public ImageView imgProduct;
    public TextView lblName;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        imgProduct = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgShelfProduct);
        imgProduct.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        imgProduct.setOnDragListener(this);
        lblName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblShelfText);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("product", view.toString());
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            Log.d(ShoppingApplication.TAG, "Started");
            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            Log.d(ShoppingApplication.TAG, "Entered");
            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            Log.d(ShoppingApplication.TAG, "Exited");
            return true;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            Log.d(ShoppingApplication.TAG, "Ended");
            return true;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**onCreateViewHolder**

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_shelf_product, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

**onBindViewHolder**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    Product product = products.get(position);
    viewHolder.lblName.setText(product.getName());
    String url = app.getImagePath();
    Picasso.with(activity).load(url).into(viewHolder.imgProduct);
}
```

Comment: Please make your ViewHolder class static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must have misunderstood the concept of the OnDragListener. It is not supposed to be added to the draggable views, but the view you want them dragged onto. So I moved it out of the RecyclerView.Adapter class and into the Activity class and added to my target view.

Now the onDrag method is only called once per trigger.